# Mega menu solution for standart joomla menu module

Tags: joomla-3.x, menu

I am working for mega menu solution width standart joomla menu module 3.x. here is my code

```
    <?php
/**
 * @package     Joomla.Site
 * @subpackage  mod_menu
 *
 * @copyright   Copyright (C) 2005 - 2016 Open Source Matters, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * @license     GNU General Public License version 2 or later; see LICENSE.txt
 */

defined('_JEXEC') or die;

$id = '';

if (($tagId = $params->get('tag_id', '')))
{
    $id = ' id="' . $tagId . '"';
}

// The menu class is deprecated. Use nav instead
?>

<ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-left <?php echo $class_sfx; ?> <?php echo $id; ?>">
<?php foreach ($list as $i => &$item)
{
    $class = 'item-' . $item->id;

    if ($item->id == $default_id)
    {
        $class .= ' default';
    }


    if (($item->id == $active_id) || ($item->type == 'alias' && $item->params->get('aliasoptions') == $active_id))
    {
        $class .= ' current';
    }

    if (in_array($item->id, $path))
    {
        $class .= ' active';
    }
    elseif ($item->type == 'alias')
    {
        $aliasToId = $item->params->get('aliasoptions');

        if (count($path) > 0 && $aliasToId == $path[count($path) - 1])
        {
            $class .= ' active';
        }
        elseif (in_array($aliasToId, $path))
        {
            $class .= ' alias-parent-active';
        }
    }

    if ($item->type == 'separator')
    {
        $class .= ' divider';
    }

    if ($item->deeper)
    {
        $class .= ' deeper';
    }

    if ($item->parent)
    {
        $attributes = array();
            if ($item->anchor_css)
            {
                $attributes['class'] = $item->anchor_css;
                $dropid = $attributes['class'];
            }
        //$class .= ' drop';
    }

    echo '<li class="' . $class . '">';

    switch ($item->type) :
        case 'separator':
        case 'component':
        case 'heading':
        case 'url':
            require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'custom_' . $item->type);
            break;

        default:
            require JModuleHelper::getLayoutPath('mod_menu', 'custom_url');
            break;
    endswitch;

    // The next item is deeper.
    if ($item->deeper)
    {
        echo '<div class="megadropdown">';
        echo '<div class="container">';
        echo '<div class="inner-megadropdown '. $dropid .'-dropdown">';
        echo '<div class="owl-wrapper">';
        echo '<ul class="horizontal-filter-posts">';
    }

    if ($item->anchor_title)
    {
        $attributes['title'] = $item->anchor_title;
        $modname = 'mod_k2_content';
        $modtitle = $attributes['title'];
        $document = JFactory::getDocument();
        $renderer = $document->loadRenderer('module');
        $module = JModuleHelper::getModule($modname,$modtitle);
        echo $renderer->render($module);
    }

    // The next item is shallower.
    elseif ($item->shallower)
    {
        echo '</li>';
        echo str_repeat('</ul></div></div></div></div></li>', $item->level_diff);
    }
    // The next item is on the same level.
    else
    {
        echo '</li>';
    }
}
?>
</ul>
```

I am using link title atribute field to render module wich I want to show in deeper, it works good but I need render module above ul but inside div classes and I have no idea how.

Comment: I personally find your question/requirements/English to be Unclear, but if your question is resolved, please award your answer the big green tick.

Answer (score 1):

I found solution for my question:

```
echo str_repeat('</ul>'.$renderer->render($module).'</div></div></div></div></li>', $item->level_diff);
```

I render module in str repeat after ul so my problem solved.